# How to enter setup Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

After installing Ubuntu 14.04 on my Dell M5030 laptop as a dual boot with Windows 7, I do not get an opportunity to enter setup.  The computer on a cold start or on a warm reboot goes directly to the Grub menu.  Is there a way to repair?  GB

Answer (score 0):

Try tapping (or holding) each of the following key combinations on a cold start:

```
<F1>
<F2>
<F3>
<F12>
```

Also try holding the `<Fn>` key and entering the above.  Some older Dell computers use an alternate key sequence instead of `<F2>` to enter System Setup. These key sequences include:

```
<Ctrl+Alt+Enter>
<Delete>
<Fn>+<F1> 
<Fn>+<Esc>
```